# finding duplicates in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like:

```
regReads=[{'QNAME': 'HWI-ST1024_0272:8:2105:10935:58524', 'FLAG': 16, 'RNAME': 'chr2', 'POS': 143138210, 'MAPQ': 42, 'CIGAR': '50M', 'RNEXT': '*', 'PNEXT': 0, 'TLEN': 0, 'SEQ': 'GAGGTCCAAACTTTAAATACTCAGAAGGATTTCTGAACTAGTTCTCTGTG', 'QUAL': 'JIJJIJJJJIGGBIIIHBCHEJIJJIIJIIJJIJIIHHDFHDDDBFFCC@'}, 
{'QNAME': 'HWI-ST1024_0272:8:1106:21049:70180', 'FLAG': 0, 'RNAME': 'chr2', 'POS': 143070473, 'MAPQ': 42, 'CIGAR': '50M', 'RNEXT': '*', 'PNEXT': 0, 'TLEN': 0, 'SEQ': 'AGGGTGACCAACTTATTCCTATTTTTCTAAGACTTTCCCCATTTTAGCAC', 'QUAL': '@CCFDDFFHHHHHJJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJIJIGI'}, 
{'QNAME': 'HWI-ST1024_0272:8:1101:7474:56141', 'FLAG': 0, 'RNAME': 'chr2', 'POS': 143045262, 'MAPQ': 42, 'CIGAR': '50M', 'RNEXT': '*', 'PNEXT': 0, 'TLEN': 0, 'SEQ': 'TTTAGCCTCCATTTCTGATTCAATCACCCAAGACAGCAGACTCAGAGTTG', 'QUAL': 'CCCFFFFFHHHHHJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJJJIJJJJJJJJFIH'}]
```

I need to find duplicate reads and remove all but one from the list. Since I can't just do "if read not in uniqueReads" (each QNAME value is unique), I was trying to do something like this, but I think I'm over-complicating this problem.

```
for read in regReads:
        compareReads.append((read['POS'],len(read['SEQ']),read['FLAG']))
    n=0
    duplicates={}
    singles=[]
    addThese=[]
    for comp in compareReads:
        if compareReads.count(comp) == 1:
            uniqueReads.append(regReads[n])
        dups=[n]
        if compareReads.count(comp) != 1:
            p=0
            for alt in compareReads:
                if comp == alt:
                    dups.append(p)
                p+=1
            duplicates[n]=sorted(dups)
        n+=1
    for dup in duplicates:
        if duplicates[dups] not in singles:
            singles.append(tuple(duplicates[dup]))
            addThese.append(dup)
    for i in addThese:
        uniqueReads.append(regReads[i])
    uniqueReadCnt=len(uniqueReads)
    print(uniqueReadCnt)
```

I just need to compare the 3 values of each dictionary (POS, FLAG, and len(SEQ)). Is there a simpler way in Python to check all entries in the list before making a decision, and then only adding that one instance from the list? I can't think of a better way to essentially "mark" the downstream duplicate reads as invalid so that they aren't add to my list of unique reads.

For the code that I currently have, I can't figure out how to move the value into the list of "singles" as a tuple (or a nested list? I'm not sure), and then check the values of each duplicates key against that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tuples as dictionary keys in Python:

```
seen = {}
for read in regReads:
    key = (read['POS'],len(read['SEQ']),read['FLAG'])
    if key not in seen:
        # first time seeing this key
        seen[key] = read
# seen.values() now contains all unique entries according to the key
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, building off the previous answer:

```
filtered = {(x['POS'],len(x['SEQ']),x['FLAG']): x for x in regReads}.values()
```

Creating a dictionary with the values that need to be unique as keys gets you a unique set of reads. Then get a list of the unique reads with .values(). Cast after if you need a true list and not a view.